# How to execute the following stored prcedure containing type as input parameter

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, toad

I have create a procedure to accept user type as input. Can anyone please let me know how can i execute the same via toad? The TYPE and PROCEDURE details are as follows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE AS OBJECT
                  (idKey NUMBER (3),
                   shortName VARCHAR2 (15),
                   fmrCusip VARCHAR2 (15),
                   incorrectTrdShares NUMBER (10),
                   incorrectTrdPrice NUMBER (10, 2),
                   incorrectTrdBuySell VARCHAR2 (15),
                   incorrectTrdCommRate NUMBER (10, 2),
                   incorrectTrdCommission NUMBER (10, 2),
                   incorrectTrdFees NUMBER (10, 2),
                   incorrectTrdNet NUMBER (10, 2),
                   correctionTrdShares NUMBER (10, 2),
                   correctionTrdPrice NUMBER (10, 2),
                   correctionTrdBuySell VARCHAR2 (15),
                   correctionTrdCommRate NUMBER (10, 2),
                   correctionTrdCommission NUMBER (10, 2),
                   correctionTrdFees NUMBER (10, 2),
                   correctionTrdNet NUMBER (10, 2),
                   currency VARCHAR2 (15),
                   fx VARCHAR2 (15),
                   netUSD NUMBER (10, 2),
                   notes VARCHAR2 (15)
                   );

CREATE or REPLACE TYPE CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE_LIST AS TABLE OF  CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GL_PROCESS_BULK_ENTRIES (p_array IN CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE_LIST, p_status out varchar2)
AS
   v_count   NUMBER;
   row_detail CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE;
BEGIN
   --p_arr_int := NEW array_int ();
   --p_arr_int.EXTEND (10);
   --len := p_array.COUNT;
   v_count := 0;

   FOR i IN 1 .. p_array.COUNT
   LOOP
      row_detail := p_array(i);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (row_detail.idKey);
      --p_arr_int (i) := v_count;
      v_count := v_count + 1;
      p_status := 'true';
   END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_count);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_status);
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         -- handle errors here...
         dbms_output.put_line('Error: '||substr(1,255,sqlerrm));
END;
/
```

Can anyone please let me know how to execute the procedure GL_PROCESS_BULK_ENTRIES?

Comment: The above problem has an update, i have a java program containing a List of bean, the bean having the same entities listed above. i want to call the above stored procedure by passing the List of that bean. How can i accomplish the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eg with some random data assigned to the table:

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2    t_mytab  CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE_LIST := CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE_LIST();
  3     v_status varchar2(10);
  4  begin
  5
  6    for idx in 1..10 loop
  7      t_mytab.extend;
  8      t_mytab(t_mytab.last) := CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE(idx, 'x', 'x', 0, 1, 'x', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'x', 1, 1, 1, 1, 'x', 'x', 2, 'foo');
  9    end loop;
 10
 11    GL_PROCESS_BULK_ENTRIES(t_mytab, v_status);
 12
 13  end;
 14  /
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
10
true

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

or you can, if you have a static list, just assign in one:

```
SQL> declare
  2    t_mytab  CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE_LIST := CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE_LIST();
  3     v_status varchar2(10);
  4  begin
  5
  6    t_mytab := CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE_LIST(
  7                CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE(123, 'x', 'x', 0, 1, 'x', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'x', 1, 1, 1, 1, 'x', 'x', 2, 'foo'),
  8                CER_GL_ENTRY_TYPE(2, 'x', 'x', 0, 1, 'x', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'x', 1, 1, 1, 1, 'x', 'x', 2, 'foo')
  9              );
 10
 11    GL_PROCESS_BULK_ENTRIES(t_mytab, v_status);
 12
 13  end;
 14  /
123
2
2
true
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Worked like a charm.

Comment: And to add to that you saved my day. Thanks again.